# Change proxy in Firefox with Vbscript?

Tags: firefox, proxy, vbscript

Is there a way to change the proxy server in firefox using vbscript?

Answer (score 1):

I could copy and paste the code, but this works - I've just tested it on my PC and its great, so here's a link:

http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1534-proxy-for-ie-and-mozilla-firefox

FYI, found it by googling "vbscript set firefox proxy" and it was the top result.